# how do I execute code in jQuery when there is certain text within a specific element?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

html part

```
<ul>
    <li><b>hi</b></li>
</ul>
```

js part

```
if($("b").contains("hi")) {
 alert('hi');
}
```

The above code is not working for me in js fiddle. I can't find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you read [the jQuery doco](http://api.jquery.com/) (why do people with jQuery questions always skip this step?) you'll see there is no `.contains()` method. But you will find the `:contains()` selector.

Comment: @nnnnnn http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/ $.contains() which is different than :contains

Comment: @roasted - Well, yes. Ironic. (Oops.) But still I _meant_ that there's no `.contains()` that operates directly as a method of a jQuery object. And if the OP was trying to use `$.contains()` they could've checked the doco and found that it was't suitable.

Comment: @nnnnnn you are right

Comment: @nnnnnn it's easy to get mislead by the jQuery docs as it's not immediately obvious there is more going on than just the matched element api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ( $("b:contains('hi')").length ) {
     alert('hi');
}
```

or

```
if ( $('b').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().indexOf('hi') != -1;
     }).length
) {
     alert('hi');
}
```